# Como inicializar componente hijo desde el padre por medio de un viewchild

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

Hola tengo una solicitud que se me ha hecho tediosa, tengo la siguiente etiqueta en el html

```
<a (click)="ngOnInit()"><li id="creacionCon" #creacion>Crear Contrato sin Precontrato Sinergia</li></a>
```

cuando doy click lo que realizo es que llamo el ngOninit pero del componente hijo desde el del padre.

```
 @ViewChild(AdminContratosCreaconComponent) creacon!: AdminContratosCreaconComponent;
ngOnInit(): void {    
 this.creacon.ngOnInit();
}
```

realice esta funcionalidad asi ya que el cliente lo solicito que fuera tipo hipervinculo y no como boton, el requiere que siempre que se de click vuelva a iniciarse el componente hijo y cargue los datos del mismo.

El inconveniente que presento es que siempre que arranca el ngOnInit de mi componente padre me genera el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este error lo genera cuando se inicializa el componente padre y trata de llamar al componente hijo.
Alguno me podria ayudar por favor!!

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo que resuelve el problema:

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'child',
  template: `{{random}}`,
})
export class Child {
  random = 0;
  // función que imita un reinicio o cambio del estado del componente
  // desde el padre
  reload() {
    this.random = Math.random();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, Child],
  template: `
  <a (click)="updateChild()">actualizar</a>
  <br><br>
    <child></child>
  `,
})
export class App {
  // se hace referencia al componente `Child`
  @ViewChild(Child) childView: Child;
  // se crea una función en el padre para llamar la función
  // `reload` del componente Child
  updateChild() {
    this.childView.reload();
  }
}
```

[Código en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5fxbmu?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Adicional a eso: no llames a las funciones del ciclo de vida `ngOnInit`, `ngAfterViewInit`, etc... directamente, es el framework el que debe encargarse de eso, llamarlas directamente puede introducir bugs a la aplicación.

Comment: Hola trate de utilizar el reload pero me actualiza toda la pgina y yo solo necesito que me vuelva a inicializar lo correspondiente a ese componente hijo

Comment: ¿Cómo usaste el reload?

Comment: En el componente padre:
importe el componente hijo como VieChild
@ViewChild(AdminContratosConsconComponent) conscon: AdminContratosConsconComponent;
y en un metodo llame la funcion reload que cree en mi componente hijo
this.conscon.reload();

en mi componente Hijo lo cree asi: 
random = 0;
  reload(){
    this.random = Math.random();
  }

cuando le doy clic por primera vez me inicializa el componente pero al volverle a dar no hace nada y no me genera tampoco error